# Calculating the right battery capacity

Tags: batteries, charge

Apologies for what is a probably an easy question but I can't wrap my head around calculating the battery size that I need. I have a circuit with total power of 2.754W and current of 1.32A.

I am interested in calculating how much capacity (in mAh I assume) a battery would need to have to power this circuit for an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is quite simple:

1320mAh.

If you are drawing 1.32A for an hour then you have 1.32Ah, or 1320mAh.

Of course, you want to give yourself a bit of a margin, so 1800-2000mAh would do the job nicely.

Comment: Thank you , this is a lot simpler than I had anticipated